# How to get name, quantity of product and balance amount?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 3 tables

**DMZ:**

```
Ndm int - number of Document
Ddm date - date of supply
Pr int - 1(income), 2(expense)
```

**DMS:**

```
Id int
Kol decimal - quantity of product
Price decimal
Ndm int - number of document foreign key with DMZ
Ktov int - id of product foreign key with TOV
```

**TOV:**

```
Ktov - id if product
Ntov - name of product
```

I need get 
Balance is the difference between income and expense.

Structure:

1. Name of product (Ntov)
2. Amount of residue
3. The amount of the balance accurate to the cent (the difference
   between what was spent and what was received during the sale)

Sorting by Ntov,
By each product ,
For each product for which there was an income and possibly an expense, one summary line in the report

Now i have this sql request, but i'm stuck :/
Help me please what i do wrong?

```
SELECT
 Ntov AS Product,
 SUM(CASE WHEN Pr = 1 then Kol*Price ELSE 0 END) AS Income,
 SUM(CASE WHEN Pr = 2 then Kol*Price ELSE 0 END) AS Expense,
 COUNT(DMS.Kol) AS LeftProducts
FROM DMS LEFT JOIN TOV
on DMS.Ktov = Tov.Ktov 
LEFT JOIN DMZ on DMS.Ndm = DMZ.Ndm
GROUP BY Ntov, Kol, Price
ORDER BY Product
```

Data of DMS: http://prntscr.com/qb3qiq 
Data of DMZ: http://prntscr.com/qb3qog 
Data of TOV: http://prntscr.com/qb3qrl 
Result: http://prntscr.com/qb3q92

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be a big help, particularly because the column names are not very meaningful.

Comment: Sorry, added screenshots with data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can aggregate and do conditional sums. Consider:

```
select
    t.ntov,
    sum(case z.pr when 1 then s.kol when 2 then - s.kol else 0 end) residue,
    sum(case z.pr when 1 then s.price when 2 then - s.price else 0 end) balance
from tov t
left join dms s on t.ktov = s.ktov
left join dmz z on s.ndm = z.ndm
group by t.ntov, t.ktov
order by t.ntov
```

Comment: Thank you, i didn't know that i can use 2 times "when"